# IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted blocking Reading on different connection to SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, transactions, timeout

Hi I've got a problem with reading from my database when the calling code has a pending transaction. Like this:

```
f1() {
DbTransaction t = Connection1.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted);
  ...
  f2();
  ...
  t.Commit();
}

f2() {
  Connection2.Execute("SELECT...");
}
```

The call to f2() results in a timeout exception.

That behaviour was surprising to me because I thought that `IsolationLevel` would allow reading access to the db. When I remove the transaction from `f1()` the problem disappears.

I am thankful for any comment son this and on how to solve the problem. I would like to keep the transaction!

(Visual Studio 2010, C#, .NET 4.0, SQL Server 2008 compatibility level 80)

Comment: You have told connection1 to read uncommitted data. You have not told connection2 that.

Answer (score 4):

As @Vijay says, it doesn't seem like you need to create a second connection here, so this problem is easily resolved by using the same connection.

For reference, though, to explain why the second connection is blocking:

Your first connection is running at an isolation level of `READ UNCOMMITTED`, which can still create exclusive locks.  At some point between creating `Connection1` and calling `f2()`, you do something to create an exclusive lock, which blocks the statement executed by `f2()`, which is running at the default isolation level of `READ COMMITTED`.

If you want to see what is occurring with locks, open two SSMS windows.  In the first window, run these statements:

```
set transaction isolation level read uncommitted
go

begin transaction 
-- alter some data
delete MyTable
waitfor delay '00:00:15'

rollback transaction
```

In the second window, run `sp_lock` to see the locks on `MyTable`.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why you are opening another connection instance in f2() as it looks like both connections are to the same DB and DB server. You can simply pass the  Connection1 instance from f1() to f2() method call and reuse.

```
f1()
{
    ...

    f2(Connection1);

    ...
}

f2()
{
    Connection1.Execute(SELECT...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a TransactionScope in a using statement to initiate these transactions.  Other than that, reuse the connection as Vijay recommended.

I believe the problem you're experiencing is related to the second connection to the same database inheriting the ambient transaction from the first connection.  I'm not sure the database providers would support multiple connections to the same database server within the same connection.

You could always open SQL studio and check the list of active locks while the second SELECT is blocking.  Pretty easy way to find out exactly what's blocking.